# RequestAccessKindAsync from Desktop Bridge

Tags: c#, uwp, push-notification, desktop-bridge, c++-winrt

I have Win32 desktop bridge application that uses background task to receive push notifications from WNS. I use UWP background task APIs over `C++-WinRT`

I'd like to be able to receive push notifications even when OS is in sleep so that it wakes up and the app handles push notification. By default OS does not wake up. It did only after manually changing settings value in `System`->`Battery`->`See which apps are affecting your battery life`->Click my app ->Uncheck `Let Windows decide` option (by default it is always checked) and check `Allow the app to run background taks`. Now I'd like to do this is manual work on code for better user experience.

[RequestAccessKindAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundexecutionmanager.requestaccesskindasync) API allows to let user to change above setting value by showing popup notification to the user and I could do it without any problem in `UWP` `C#` sample app. But same code does not show pop notification from my desktop bridge over `C++-WinRT`. It simply returns false value for below code

```
auto result = co_await BackgroundExecutionManager::RequestAccessKindAsync(BackgroundAccessRequestKind::AlwaysAllowed, 
    L"App needs to use background to catch push notifications while device is in sleep");
```

Can anyone confirm that `RequestAccessKindAsync` API works from desktop bridge? If not then how I can make sure OS and the app will always be able to wake up from sleep when it receives push notification?

UPD: Raised request to enable this API from desktop brige [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/36953818-requestaccesskindasync-from-desktop-bridge)

Comment: [While packaged apps can register background tasks, only fully UWP apps can run as a background task.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api) So, if you call this API from desktop app, it will not work.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT do you want to say I can run this API from my background task? I have tried to do so and got same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a missing feature. When we designed this API a couple of releases ago we didn't consider desktop bridge apps would be calling it - but clearly there is a use case for supporting this. I have notified the team about this gap, but I'd also encourage you to log a feature request here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/

Two possible workarounds:
(1) you could add a dummy/empty UWP foreground app to your desktop bridge app. You can then launch this on startup and request the background access from there. This will be a bit ugly, but you could make it look like a splash screen :-)
(2) you can instruct the user to go into the Settings app to set your app to always allowed. You can help them do that with a deep link to the battery save settings, but they will still need to manually flip the switch.

Comment: I tried with (1) option earlier. I added dummy UWP App into desktop bridge's manifest as a 2nd Application and it solved my problem. But I cannot upload app package with 2 applications to the Store. Do you think there is another way I can add dummy UWP into desktop bridge?

Comment: Did you set AppListEntry="none" for the second app in the appxmanifest (so that it won't show in the app list)? With that you should be able to submit to the store. If you get a WACK error ignore it, they should admit your app. If they don't, send me mail (swick [@] microsoft.com) and I will help you get it approved.

Comment: I added `<uap:VisualElements AppListEntry="none"` to the second app and can see single desktop application is installed(UWP was there as well previously). But still getting `The Microsoft Store does not support a package containing more than one applications` error. Will try to upload this to the Store.

Comment: Yep, ignore that message. Apps that declare 'runFullTrust' are exempt from that multi-app package rule.

Comment: While uploading my app to the store, I got following error `xxx.appx specifies a headless app. You don't have permission to create a headless app. Please update AppListEntry="none" in the AppxManifest file and also ensure you have the waiver "HeadlessAppBypass" associated to this app.` Do you know if there is any way I can workaround this error?

Comment: Please send me an email with your app is and account name - swick [at] microsoft.com

Comment: We defined an "appAlias" Declaration for the app to fix the HeadlessAppBypass error. Here are more details: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=35515#p115673